# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tokenable_id' cannot be null

Tags: postman, laravel-7, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

i want use laravel sanctum with 2 model

this is code for user model

```
<?php namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use HasApiTokens,Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
   'id', 'name', 'family','gender','birhday','national_code','email','mobile','profie_pic','province_code','city_code','address','username','role','status','password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token','role',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
```

}

and usercontroller for function login is :

```
public function login(Request $request) { 
$user= User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
if (!$user || !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    return response([
        'message' => ['These credentials do not match our records.']
    ], 404);
}

$token = $user->createToken('my-app-token')->plainTextToken;
$response = [
    'user' => $user,
    'token' => $token
];
 return response($response, 201);
```

}

and token is true and all route with middleware('auth:sanctum') is working true but i want so use model nurces and write this code
first:model nurces:

```
class Nurces extends model
{
use HasApiTokens,Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'family','gender','birhday','national_code','email','mobile','profie_pic','province_code','city_code','address','username','status','password',
 ];

 /**
  * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
  *
  * @var array
  */
 protected $hidden = [
     'password','remember_token',
 ];
 protected $primaryKey = 'nurces_id';
```

}

and function login in nurcescontroller is :

```
public function login(Request $request) { 
$nurces= Nurces::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if (!$nurces || !Hash::check($request->password, $nurces->password)) {
    return response([
        'message' => ['These credentials do not match our records.']
    ], 404);
}

 $token = $nurces->createToken('my-nurces-token-')->plainTextToken;

$response = [
    'nurces' => $nurces,
    'token' => $token
];

 return response($response, 201);
```

}
when use postman and login with this address - this erorr :

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'tokenable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (my-nurces-token-, fa55707e2bd9e1b71f8e5ebc0623f9ce1cc8e49f5b6e1ff804dda262e93811f4, [\"*\"], ?, App\\Nurces, 2020-07-05 11:18:58, 2020-07-05 11:18:58))",
```

Comment: Column 'tokenable_id' cannot be null :-  so either pass the value to it or make that column nullable

Answer (score 8):

I think, there is an mismatch between primary key of **App\Nurces** model.

As per documentation and error, two columns values of ***personal_access_tokens*** table as follows:

- tokenable_type -  model name      **e.g
  App\Model\User**
- tokenable_id -  primary key of model

In your case, **tokenable_id** value trying to insert as ***NULL***, that's why getting error.

Please check and confirm primary key column name of **App\Nurces** model. Add the below property in the **Nurces** model class.

**protected $primaryKey = '**primary key column name**';**

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

class Nurces extends model => class Nurces extends Authenticatable
just like model\user.php